# Java: how to define function from constuctor?

Tags: java

I have a java object and I want to define one of its functions from the constuctor. How do I define a function of the object in the constuctor?

Basicly something like this.

```
public class Thing{

  public Thing(String str){
    //define F
  }

  public float F(float x){
   //to be defined
  }
}
```

My goal is to have the the Thing object constuctor take in a math function in form of string (eg "2*x"), parse it and define the F function to preform that expression. So that if I were to create a new Thing object as such

```
Thing test = new Thing("2*x");
```

the F function of the test object would be defined like this

```
public float F(float x){
  return 2*x;
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: _"define one of its functions from the constuctor"_ doesn't make sense in Java.  You will need to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking in terms of functional programming whereas Java is an object oriented language. I would advise that you research the differences in these two paradigms.

Comment: Could do this with a lambda. Or an anonymous inner subclass of Thing. Somewhat unclear what you're asking about here, so difficult to answer.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because what you're asking is extremely unclear.  It's almost like you're stringing computer sciency words into gramatically correct sentences.   You can't define functions from within constructors.  Your use of "How can I X of the Y in the Z" is too complex an artifact for even you to understand what you're saying, let alone us.  You need to slow down and work on communication via writing, if you can revisit this text later with fresh eyes, you too might say: "what on earth is this person even talking about?".  Improve writing and communication skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a `Function` to your constructor:

```
public class Thing {

    private DoubleFunction<Float> func;

    public Thing(DoubleFunction<Float> func) {
        this.func = func;
    }

    public float F(float x) {
        return func.apply(x);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DoubleFunction<Float> myFunc = d -> d * 2;
Thing thing = new Thing(myFunc);
thing.F(2.0); // Result in 4.0
```

Comment: If this is all you're doing, though, there's literally no point in the `Thing` class--it's just an incompatible reimplementation of `DoubleFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class Thing {

    private UnaryOperator<Float> func;

    public Thing() {
        func = x -> 2 * x;
    }

    public float F(float x) {
        return func.apply(x);
    }
}
```